# Wordpress Admin login redirect to homepage

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, redirect, login, cookies

Wordpress admin page redirecting to home page after login, not at all see any admin area. For the console, it is showing 32 redirects. but not sure why it is happening[image: console]
For the console header, it is showing as below image.

[image]

Now I was not able to login to the admin, please help, we have used a plugin called wp-hide-login for hiding login, even it is disabled through FTP, unable to login through wp-admin.

Comment: Did you try to delete all cookie ? On security tab or try with another browser.
Otherwise, check in .htaccess if some rules has been added to it.

Comment: Take a look at your .htaccess file (web.config for IIS users).  It is likely that your plugin modified that file. That would explain why you are still redirecting after disabling the plugin.  If you're not sure what to look for, reset back to a [default .htaccess](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/) setup.

Comment: Thank You for Your answers. This issue is resolved. There was a script added in the functions.php file, that was doing the non Admin users redirect to home.